# Mat checkbox not being checked when manually setting it to true inside a method

Tags: angular

I am using mat checkbox & want the checkbox to remain checked even if the user clicks on it provided some condition is met. However I can't seem to get it to work. Seems like I'm missing some detail. Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is my html:

```
            <mat-checkbox (change)="isValidState($event)" [(ngModel)]="checkboxState">Admin</mat-checkbox>
```

The method that I'm calling on change:

```
 isValidState(event: any): void {
  if(some condition)
  {
    this.checkboxState = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but you shouldn't be doing it in `(change)` output.  The reason why it's not working is that, because when you click the checkbox, first it's going through your `isValidState()` method, and then it's changing the value of the checkbox itself.
You can wrap it like that:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.checkboxState = false;
})
```

But this is not a good way of handling things in angular.

The thing I like to do, is to use reactive forms. I will give you a code example how it would look for your checkbox:

```
export class AppComponent {
  someCondition = true;
  myCheckBox = new FormControl();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myCheckBox.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      if(this.someCondition) {
        this.myCheckBox.setValue(false, {emitEvent: false})
      }
    })
  }
}
```

and html:

```
<mat-checkbox [formControl]="myCheckBox">Admin</mat-checkbox>
```

For me, it makes it easier to control your forms, and all the projects I have been working with were also using this approach.